# launchd seemingly ignores SockNodeName

Tags: macos, launchd, plist

I want to bind a launchd service so that it's accessible only to the machine where the service is running via socket activation; no external network access.

I have a `.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` that contains:

```xml
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
    <key>Listeners</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SockType</key>
        <string>dgram</string>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <string>domain</string>
        <key>SockNodeName</key>
        <string>127.0.0.1</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

If I start the service, I can see that it's bound to `localhost:domain`

```
$ launchctl bootstrap gui/(id -u) ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my-service.plist;
$ lsof -i UDP:53
COMMAND      PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
my-service  7223 sbaildon   10u  IPv4 0x8c23a21d8eeb432f      0t0  UDP localhost:domain
```

Once I make a request, the same service becomes available at `*:domain`

```
$ dig stackoverflow.com @127.0.0.1 -p 53 >/dev/null
$ lsof -i UDP:53
COMMAND      PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
my-service  7223 sbaildon   10u  IPv4 0x8c23a21d8eeb432f      0t0  UDP *:domain
```

What's going on with `launchd`?